# Managing environments in a FastAPI app using Docker

Tags: python, api, development-process, development-environment

Bit of context: I'm an Economics major that somehow ended up developing an API that's becoming a whole software project, so please bear with me.

So, after I got asked to add logs I noticed I should have a development and a production environment so my logs don't get dirtied by my tests. After reading a bit I added a `.env` and a `.env.development` file. A bit overkill because they look like this:

`.env`:

```
 ENVIRONMENT=production
```

`.env.development`:

```
 ENVIRONMENT=development
```

In the future there might be database connections, so I'd rather keep this structure if possible.

Now, I also installed `python-dotenv` to load my environment variables, my code looks a bit like this:

```
import logging
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.env.development')

if os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT') == 'production':
    log_dir = 'logs/logs_completo.log'
    log_error_dir = 'logs/logs_error.log'
elif os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT') == 'development':
    log_dir = 'logs/logs_completo_dev.log'
    log_error_dir = 'logs/logs_error_dev.log'
```

So, my only problem is that, as it looks right now, the correct loading of an environment depends on me remembering to manually change `load_dotenv('.env.development')` to `load_dotenv('.env')` and vice versa.

Also, I'm developing on Windows and the docker machine uses Linux. My question is, how can I automate my environment selection, so I don't accidentally send the development environment to production or accidentally work on production environment while testing? Should I add a bash file or something like that? How does that work with testing on Windows?

Thanks a lot and sorry if I'm using some concepts incorrectly.

Comment: There's the quite reasonable idea from "The 12 Factor App" that [configuration should be provided by the "environment"](http://12factor.net/config). Somehow this led to dotenv being created as an awful config file format. At least, the [dotenv JS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv/) points out that your shouldn't commit dotenv files and shouldn't have dev/prod dotenv files. Instead, have a local file that makes sense on your system, and a file on your prod system (maybe created during your deployment process). In your case I'd also configure a logging target, not a name like "dev".

Comment: If you're using docker then I would avoid `.env` files and put environment-specific configuration inside a more suitable format such as YAML or JSON instead.   `docker run` or `docker-compose` can simply pass the name of the environment when creating a container.     e.g. `docker run -e ENVIRONMENT='development'`     --  you could name the yaml/json files based on this too - e.g. `development.yaml`, `test.yaml`, `staging.yaml`, `production.yaml`, etc.